# Comparing Strings in MATLAB Problem

Tags: string, matlab, base64, encode

I've been fiddling around with my program and I've been using a modified version of urlread that allows for BASIC authentication.  The problem is that I have to include the following line of code to the base urlread function:

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty('Authorization', 'Basic passphrase');
```

...where passphrase is the a base64 encoded string of 'user:pass'.  If I place the passphrase directly into the string on that line the program will work just fine, the trouble starts when I try to concatenate to get that resulting 'Basic passphrase' string.  Initially I just had:

```
['Basic', ' ', passphrase]
```

After that did not work I did some exploring and experimenting around in the command window.:

```
passphrase = 'somerandompassphrase';
teststr1 = ['Basic', ' ', passphrase];
teststr2 = ['Basic', ' ', 'somerandompassphrase'];
teststr3 = 'Basic somerandompassphrase';
strcmp(teststr1, teststr2)
strcmp(teststr1, teststr3)
strcmp(teststr2, teststr3)
```

The output is 1, or true for each one (as expected).  However if I take the base64encode of 'somerandompassphrase' (which is 'c29tZXJhbmRvbXBhc3NwaHJhc2U='):

```
encoded = base64encode(passphrase);
teststr1 = ['Basic', ' ', encoded];
teststr2 = ['Basic', ' ', 'c29tZXJhbmRvbXBhc3NwaHJhc2U='];
strcmp(teststr1, teststr2)
```

The output is 0, or false.  Shouldn't it be true though?  The base64encode function can be found [here](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/matlab/software/util/datautil/base64encode.m).

Even from a quick test of:

```
strcmp(encoded, 'c29tZXJhbmRvbXBhc3NwaHJhc2U=')
```

The output is still 0.

Please help, I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured this out right before I posted the question, but I figured I'd go ahead and leave it up in case people run into the same problem as I did.

The problem is from the base64encode function.  It automatically adds a newline character to the end of the string, causing the strcmp function to return false.  To fix this you can include a parameter for the optional parameter to the base64encode function, if you put in a blank string it won't add a newline character to the end of it causing it to work.

```
encoded = base64encode(passphrase, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/07/06/calling-java-from-matlab/), you can also use the [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoder from the the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) Java library which comes bundled with MATLAB and is available on the classpath:

```
encoder = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64();
b64str = char( encoder.encode(passphrase-0) )';
```